# Verifying that OJDBC drivers are updated correctly in weblogic?

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, ojdbc

We have upgraded our Oracle database to version 12. We have a Java application running Java 7 on Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0 with a database connection using the driver class name: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.

I cannot find any `ojdbc7.jar` drivers anywhere if I do a search in my weblogic installation folder `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home` however I can find `ojdbc6.jar` in the location `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.2.0`.

I am trying to upgrade to `ojdbc7.jar`. According to the site [Fusion Middleware Configuring and Managing JDBC Data Sources for Oracle WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/ds_12cdriver.htm#JDBCA636) I need to set the following drivers on my class path:

- ojdbc7.jar
- ojdbc7_g.jar
- ojdbc7dms.jar
- ons.jar
- oraclepki.jar
- orai18n.jar
- orai18n-mapping.jar
- osdt_cert.jar
- osdt_core.jar
- ucp.jar

I downloaded the first few from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) and the rest I found in my weblogic installation folder already. I copied them into a folder `D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7`.

And I added to my class path all the jars to:

```
D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd

set WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\ojdbc7.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\ojdbc7_g.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\ojdbc7dms.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\ons.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\oraclepki.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\orai18n.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\orai18n-mapping.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\osdt_cert.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\osdt_core.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc7\ucp.jar;D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.pki_12.1.2;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%PROFILE_CLASSPATH%;%ANT_HOME%/lib/ant-all.jar;%ANT_CONTRIB%/lib/ant-contrib.jar;%CAM_NODEMANAGER_JAR_PATH%
```

I also went to the windows registry of my service and added the same jars to my CLASSPATH cmd line arguments.

If my application starts up I can see the jars is in my classpath.

But how can I verify which ojdbc drivers are actually being used?
And is this the correct way of updating the drivers?

(Now before people start saying we should not run Java 7 apps anymore... This is a legacy app that will be replaced soon but for now this is what I have to work with :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I verify which ojdbc drivers are actually being used?

You may ask the driver `getMetaData` method.

Simple example of the relevant part (`conn` is the database connection).

```
md = conn.getMetaData();
println (md.getDriverVersion());
```

This gives e.g.

```
 12.1.0.2.0
```

This is the version you find in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of the used driver jar.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.75-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 12.1.0.2.0
```

Important thing while updating the JDBC environment is to check the [JDBC Compatibility Matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01)

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct documentation link.  Looking at that page, it says to do a custom install of the client kit.  That means that you need to get all of the listed jar files from that kit.  You can't use a new ojdbc7.jar file from the kit and the ucp.jar file that comes with WLS.  They need to be a matched set.
If you are using FMW or FA, you need to use ojdbc7dms.jar.  Otherwise, use ojdbc7.jar.  ojdbc7_g.jar is only for debugging.

Using conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion() will tell you the version of ojdbc7.jar you are using but it won't tell you that you have a mismatched set of jar files.

Comment: I can find the following drivers from here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/ds_12cdriver.htm#CHDBJCBD) ojdbc7.jar, ojdbc7_g.jar, orai18n.jar and ons.jar but not the others. 

Do I still require the rest? And if I only apply the above ones to the class path... when it needs those I didn't add to the class path it will still find the existing ones on the path. Will that cause any issues?

Comment: The official answer is yes, you need a complete matched set to have a supported configuration.  If you don't have a matched set, you may run into a latent bug that is difficult to track down.  It ultimately depends on what features your application is using and what classes those features access.  Further, there are actually two branches of the ons.jar file and if you get the wrong one, that's a problem.  There are a lot of things that depend on ucp.jar.  If you use secure connections, you need the 3 security jar files.  Using XML, you need the xdb jar file.